# Why does this cron job run every minute?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I ran a cron job as ec2 user, in AWS server.

```
I set the cron command, like this   
*/5  *  *  *  *    ec2-user     bash ./dailyMailSend.sh
```

in **crontab -e**  file.

It was set to run after every 5 minutes. But it runs every minute. Don't know why ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sorry @jww  but this type of questions was asked before here, therefore i asked it here.

Comment: What makes you to think it runs every minute? `./dailyMailSend.sh` - Avoid using relative path in crontab. Specify absolute/full path.

Comment: I checked the file, all paths were written in absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

For Amazon Linux use "`0/5`" instead of "`*/5`". This expression means every 5th minute from 0 through 59.

Next, do not specify relative paths in your crontab. Use only absolute paths.

Comment: I did that, but the result was same.